# Connection with JSoup via proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup

```
 System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<proxyip>"); // set proxy server
 System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxyport>");  //set proxy port
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://your.url.here").get(); // Jsoup now connects via proxy
```

I have a script that will log in to a website by proxy.
I tried to check if it works by adding a fake proxy to a specific user,  and the problem is that it will login even if proxy is fake, so it should not login or post.

I use the code above for calling proxy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSoup's connection is actually based on `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. This is the reason why the system proxies are valid for JSoup in the first place.

The way `HttpURLConnection` works is by using a `ProxySelector` object, which returns all possible proxies for the given URI.

When `HttpURLConnection` tries to connect to the URL, it first tries to connect to each of the proxies in the list. If the connection to the proxy in the list fails, it tries the next, and so on. But if none of the proxies are reachable, **it defaults to direct connection**.

If you were using the `HttpURLConnection` class directly, you could use the `usingProxy()` method, which, after connecting, tells you whether the connection is going through a proxy or not. But since your `HttpURLConnection` is wrapped in an `org.jsoup.Connection` object, this method is not available to you.

To sum up:

- When you give it a fake proxy, it will not refuse to connect. It will simply connect directly, without proxy.
- Using the `Jsoup.connect()` method, you can't know for sure if it went through the proxy or not. Note that even if you use a real proxy, but it happens to be temporarily unreachable, the connection will be direct.

If it's important to you that the connection will not work unless it goes through the proxy, you should use a different class to connect (you can use `HttpURLConnection` or the Apache `HttpCore` or whatever works for you), and after making sure the connection is going through the proxy, get an `InputStream` from that connection, and use [`Jsoup.parse()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to parse the HTML.

Comment: You can see the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#759)